# Syntax in conditional expression comparing with regex

Tags: bash, shell, syntax

I have tried to execute the code below on my Ubuntu machine, but it keeps saying "syntax error in conditional expression" and "syntax error near '0-9'" can you tell me why?

```
while ! [[ $num =~ ^[ 0-9 ] +$ && $num = 0 ]] ; do
```

Comment: `[[ $num = 0 ]]` is string comparison, so having it there makes the regex match useless. If you want to check if the variable is nonempty and compares as zero, you could use `[[ -n $num && $num -eq 0 ]]` or `[ -n "$num" ] && [ "$num" -eq 0 ]`. Either would accept stuff like `000` and `000 `, but not the empty string.

Answer (score 5):

Your while shouldn't be capitalized but I think that only happened when typing into this question otherwise you would get a different error.

Your issue is likely just that your regular expression is wrong.

`[ 0-9 ]` should be `[0-9]` with no spaces.  Once you fix that however you will get a different error about `+$` because you will also need to escape the space between them.

```
while ! [[ $num =~ ^[0-9]\ +$ && $num = 0 ]] ; do
```

It's often better to store patterns like this in a variable for use with the extended test:

```
pattern='^[0-9] +$'
while ! [[ $num =~ $pattern && $num -eq 0 ]]; do
```

Comment: ...and note that you here, you must not quote `$pattern`, since otherwise it's taken as literal and not a regex.